# How to use shortcode inside shortcode (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my own function to create a shortcode. Function will get the category, and display the post contents. But, if I used some shortcode inside my post. Function is working, but post shortcode will show as like shortcode `[gallery]`.

```
/*------------------------------------------*/
/**[cat] shortcode function - by Yesh**/
/*------------------------------------------*/
function categoryShortcode($atts) {
  //Extract Shotcode from the pages and posts
  extract(shortcode_atts(array('slug' => 'default'), $atts));
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category_name' => $atts['slug'], 'orderby'  => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC');
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  $html="";
  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $category = get_the_category(); //Get the category from the post
    $cat_img = z_taxonomy_image_url(get_category_by_slug($category[1]->name)->term_id);//Get image url from the child category 
    $html.='<div id="parent-cat-image-'.$category[1]->name.'" style="margin-top:-42px;background-position:right center;height:580px;background-image:url('.$cat_img.');">';
    $html.='<div id="cat-title">';
    $html.='<p id="parent-name">'.get_category_by_slug($category[0]->name)->name.'</p>';
    $html.='<h1 id="cat-name">'.$category[1]->name.'</h1>';
    $html.='<p id="read-more">Read More</p>';
    $html.='</div>';
    $html.='</div>';
    $html.='<div id="pack-post-content-'.$category[1]->name.'" style="min-height:400px;display:none;">';
    $html.='<div id="contents" class="post-cont">';
    $html.= $post->post_content;
    $html.='</div>';
    $html.='</div>';
  }
  return $html;
}
add_shortcode('cat', 'categoryShortcode');
```

I need to extract the post shortcode in this foreach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced `$html.= $post->post_content;`

Using this `$html.= do_shortcode($post->post_content);`

It will extract your post, page contents shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
do_shortcode
```

You call that function and pass the shortcode you want to execute.

Example:

```
echo do_shortcode('[foo]'); or $var = do_shortcode('[foo]');
```

Here's the link to the [do_shortcode documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not perfectly match for me. B'cuz, client can use any of shorcode in side the post. As a example "in wordpress, there have lot of default shortcodes" so, I can't use exactly one shortcode to extract. Finally I found one my own please see my answer. Anyway! Thanks in advanced.